# ReloadData is not working for a UICollectionView

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, reload

I would like to change my entier array used to created all my cells with a button and then reload my collection view, but it is not working. I've tried to reload the collection view into the main thread but it also not working

I've tried to reload the collection view into the main thread, or just using collectionView.reloadData() but it also not working

```swift
 @IBAction func BicepsBtn(_ sender: Any) {
        self.current = "Biceps"
        Data = user.getMuscleDataChart(typeMuscle: current)
        listMuscle = user.getListMuscle(typeMuscle: current)
        collectionView.reloadData()
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return listMuscle.count
    }

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)
        let switchView = cell.viewWithTag(1000) as? UISwitch
        let titleView = cell.viewWithTag(1001) as? UILabel

        if let titleView = titleView, let switchView = switchView {
        titleView.text = self.listMuscle[indexPath.row].label
        titleView.textColor = self.listMuscle[indexPath.row].color
        switchView.tag = indexPath.row
        switchView.addTarget(self, action: #selector(yourFunc),
                                 for: UIControl.Event.valueChanged)
        }
        return cell
    }
```

Here is my current code, when the user is going to click on the Biceps button, the function will fetch all data about this muscle and then trying to reload.
Any idea ?
Thanks in advance

Comment: you need to debug you code. the way to do that is to start splitting the problems. for example, replace user.getListMuscle with explicit 1 muscle object. you need to get to the point that something IS WORKING and then start testing the change one by one (not the opposite)

Comment: I also tried to change all label by another string but It also not worked :/ And when I get my list of muscle corresponding to the biceps the array is correct, is there any way to re call the collectionView function that return each cell again ?

Comment: @user1105951 I tried your idea, and my collection view got a length of 1 now so it's great, but the label didn't change...

Comment: Seems to me that the collectionView is reloading before all the data is pulled. Try to reload in a closure. https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Closures.html